# Spring evict cache from method with another signature

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I cache some queries in one method

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "user-actions")
    public UserAction getUserAction(UUID userId) {
        ...
    }
```

I'd like to evict cache in another method. It works if method has the same signature, for example

```
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user-actions")
    public void evictUserLevel(UUID userId) {
        log.info("Cache user-actions has been evicted");
    }
```

But is there ways to evict cache if I don't pass `userId` to method in which cache will be evicted, or if it has more than one parameter? This doesn't work:

```
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user-actions")
    public void processEvent(UserEvent event, UUID userId) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Specify the method argument to use as the cache key (or set the cache to evict all).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user-events", key = "#root.args[1]")
    public void processEvent(UserEvent event, UUID userId) {
        ...
    }
```

`root.args` - means method arguments and `[1]` - is an index of an argument

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key)

### Default Key Generation

Since caches are essentially key-value stores, each invocation of a cached method needs to be translated into a suitable key for cache access. Out of the box, the caching abstraction uses a simple `KeyGenerator` based on the following algorithm:

- If no params are given, return 0.
- If only one param is given, return that instance.
- If more the one param is given, return a key computed from the hashes of all parameters.

---

Hence below signature does not work as key is computed from `event` and `userId`.

```java
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user-actions")
public void processEvent(UserEvent event, UUID userId) {
   ...
}
```

---

> But is there ways to evict cache if I don't pass userId to method in which cache will be evicted, or if it has more than one parameter?

### For no parameter

set `allEntries=true`, which will clear all entries.

```java
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user-actions", allEntries = true)
public void evictAll() {
}
```

### For more than one parameter

specify the parameter for the `key`, refer to [Custom Key Generation Declaration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) for details.

```java
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user-actions", key = "#userId")
public void processEvent(UserEvent event, UUID userId) {
...
}
```